# How to build GraphQL schema for reverse lookup from Content Type model to usual model?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django

I have 4 types of profiles. Some fields are the same, some are different. Each profile has its own url, so I use ContentType as a central place of mappring urls<->profiles.

```
# profiles/models.py
class Sport(models.Model):
    pass

class ProfileAbstract(models.Model):
    pass

class ProfileOrganization(ProfileAbstract):
    pass

class ProfilePlace(ProfileAbstract):
    pass

class ProfileTeam(ProfileAbstract):
    pass

class ProfileUser(ProfileAbstract):
    pass

class ProfileURL(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)  # Url

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)  # CharField because I use UUID
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

P.S. Example of direct lookup can be found [in this github issue](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-django/issues/11).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# profiles/schema.py
import graphene

from graphene_django.types import DjangoObjectType

from .models import (ProfileOrganization, ProfilePlace, ProfileTeam, ProfileUser,ProfileURL, Sport)

# [ START: Types ]
class SportType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Sport


class ProfileURLType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileURL

    slug = graphene.String()
    model_name = graphene.String()

    def resolve_slug(self, info):
        return self.slug

    def resolve_model_name(self, info):
        return self.content_object.__class__.__name__  # ex. 'ProfileTeam'


class ProfileOrganizationType(DjangoObjectType):
    """
    Use this class as a basic class for other Profile Types classes
    """

    class Meta:
        model = ProfileOrganization
        fields = ('name', 'logo_data', 'profile_url')

    profile_url = graphene.Field(ProfileURLType)

    def resolve_profile_url(self, args):
        return self.profile_url.first()


class ProfilePlaceType(ProfileOrganizationType):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfilePlace


class ProfileTeamType(ProfileOrganizationType):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileTeam


class ProfileUserType(ProfileOrganizationType):
    class Meta:
        model = ProfileUser


class ProfileTypeUnion(graphene.Union):
    class Meta:
        types = (ProfileOrganizationType, ProfileTeamType, ProfilePlaceType, ProfileUserType)
# [ END: Types ]


# [ START: Queries ]
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    """
    EXAMPLE OF QUERY:

    query profileDetails {
      profileDetails(profileUrl: "8auB-pMH-6Sh") {
        ... on ProfileTeamType {
          id,
          name,
          skillLevel,
          sport {
            name
          },
          profileUrl {
            slug,
            modelName
          }
        }

        ... on ProfilePlaceType {
          id,
          name,
          sports {
            name
          },
          profileUrl {
            slug,
            modelName
          }
        }
      }
    }
    """

    profile_details = graphene.Field(ProfileTypeUnion, required=True, profile_url=graphene.String())

    def resolve_profile_details(self, info, profile_url):
        profile_url_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='profiles', model='profileurl')
        profile_url_inst = profile_url_type.get_object_for_this_type(slug=profile_url)

        return profile_url_inst.content_object
# [ END: Queries ]
```

`...  on ProfileTeamType` is inline fragments ([details](https://graphqlmastery.com/blog/how-to-query-your-schema-with-graphql-fragments)).
As you can see, we query 2 fragments in the example above (however in my case it should be 4, according to the number of profiles type), but just one fragment/model returns data - the one which refers to the provided `profileUrl` in the query.

---

From front end side based on the received `modelName` we can handle fields according to our needs.

Also the query mentioned above with fragments > 1 throws 2 errors in browser's console (I use Apollo client on Front End):

1. > You are using the simple (heuristic) fragment matcher, but your
   >   queries contain union or interface types. Apollo Client will not be
   >   able to accurately map fragments. To make this error go away, use the
   >   `IntrospectionFragmentMatcher` as described in the docs:
   >   https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/fragments.html#fragment-matcher

(error has incorrect link. The correct one is [this](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/fragments/).)

2. > WARNING: heuristic fragment matching going on!.

It seems this is a bug ([github issue](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/3397)).

In order to fix it, in Apollo settings we need to add cache option, which should look like:

```
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { InMemoryCache, IntrospectionFragmentMatcher } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';

const fragmentMatcher = new IntrospectionFragmentMatcher({
  introspectionQueryResultData: {
    __schema: {
      types: []
    }
  }
})

const cache = new InMemoryCache({ fragmentMatcher });

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link: new HttpLink(),
});
```